# Poisson regression on gravity model

Tags: r, regression, gravity

For a university project, I am trying to fit a regression model for demand to a number of independent variables. I tried to include a small example, but it didn't work as a figure (as I am new to this). Instead, see the following link to view a sample of the dataset that I am using:

[image]

In this table, the first column indicates country pairs, columns 2 to 6 are independent variables, and the final column is the depedent variable. What I would like to do, is to perform regression analysis, assuming that this data can be described by a gravity equation.

I know that people frequently use log-linearisation to solve this. However, as I am dealing with zeros in my data (and don't to distort the data by adding small constants), and as I assume that heteroskedasticity is in the data, I would like to use a different method. Based on what Santos 2006 described (in his paper "The log of gravity"), I would like to use Poisson Pseudo Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

However, I am fairly new to using R (or any statistical software), and I cant figure out how to do this in R. Can anybody help me with this? The only thing I've found so far is that the glm commands poisson and quasipoisson could be used (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/252476.html).

I've searched for help in documents on glm, but I don't understand how to use the glm function to solve this gravity model? How do I specify that I want the model in the form:

`DEM = RP^alpha1 * GDPC_O^alpha2 * GDPC_D^alpha3 * POP_O^alpha4....` and then use the regression to solve for the different alphas?

Comment: Have a look at `?family`. This question may be useful also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20826/229

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say precisely without more detail, but

```
glm(DEM ~ log(RP) + log(GDPC_O) + log(GDPC_D) + log(POP_O),
     data=your_data,
     family=quasipoisson(link="log"))
```

should work reasonably well.  The intercept will be the log of the proportionality constant; the other coefficients will be the exponents
of the respective terms (this works because the log link says that `log(DEM) = beta_0 + beta_1*log(RP) + ...`; if you exponentiate both sides you get `DEM = exp(beta_0) * exp(log(RP)*beta_1) * ...` or `DEM = C*RP^beta_1*...`

PS it is not necessary, but it may be helpful for interpretation to scale and center your predictor variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does your answer also work for zeros in the data, without removing them? Because that's why I wanted to use (quasi)poisson, as these methods should be able to work with zero-trade flows without removing the data.

Comment: I did try your method, but it didn't work before. It seems to work now (I had some errors in my dataframe), thank you! :) 

However, I am new to using Poisson regressions, so I don't know how to interpret the results, and if they make sense or not. I will look for more information on how to interpret the results from R's Poisson regression!

Comment: as I tried to clarify in my answer, the coefficients (other than the intercepts) of the Poisson model are the exponents/alpha values in the gravity model equations.

Comment: Thank you Ben. From your earlier explanation, I understood that part. However, I was wondering how to interpret the results in terms of how the data fits the model, because this poisson regression doesn't give R-squared.

Comment: By the way, the results of the Poisson regression are in the following link (I can't post figures) : http://i.stack.imgur.com/msbjv.png . The factors COL, LAN, LL_O and LL_D are dummy variables.

Comment: the follow-up questions (I did already answer your primary question ...) are turning this into a followup [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) question, maybe you can post it there (with a link to this question).  By the way, it's easy to cut-and-paste *text* (rather than screenshots) into a SO/CV question to show your results ...